# Why inherited objects members are accessible by key but 'hidden'?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

While playing with JavaScript (which is pretty new for me), I found some strange behaviour:

```
var some_object = {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: "moo"
};

console.log(some_object); // { foo: 'bar', baz: 'moo' }

var inherited_object = Object.create(some_object);
console.log(inherited_object); // {} 
console.log(inherited_object.baz); // moo
```

Inherited object looks 'empty' but its members are still accessible by key. What is going on here and what logic stands behind such behaviour?

Comment: Note that on `console.log(inherited_object); // {} ` (in chrome at least), you can expand the entry in the console log and still see the prototypical properties.

Comment: This question seems to be about `console.log`, not JS in general.

Comment: @James Thorpe I'm running code with NodeJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how *prototypal inheritance* works.

When you use `Object.create` to create a new object from existing object, the properties are inherited from the object from which the object is being created. So, the object that is newly created may look empty but contains *reference* to the inherited properties from parent.

The inherited object's reference is stored in the `__proto__` link of the object which contains reference to the parent object properties.

When you access a non-existing property on object, it's prototype is searched for the property, if not found its parent is searched until the grandparent `Object`. If the property is not found in `Object` then error/message is returned.

```
_____________              _____________              ______________
|Own Members|       -----> |     foo    |          -->| toString() |
|           |       |      |     bar    |          |  |  valueOf() |
|           |       |      |            |          |  |            |
|___________|       |      |____________|          |  |            |
| __proto__ |-------|      |  __proto__ |-----...--   |            |
-------------              --------------             --------------

inherited_obj              some_obj                       Object
```

Notice that the all the objects except `Object` has prototype link.

**The prototype chain is not hidden, you can see that if you log it, inside the `__proto__` property.**

Answer (score 3):

That's Javascript's *prototype chain*. Whenever you access a property on an object, Javascript first checks if the actual object has that property, and if not checks if the object's prototype has that property, and if not if *that* object's prototype has that property and so on...

`console.log` limits itself to the "first level" of properties in direct outputs, but in modern Javascript consoles you can typically click and expand the object's `__proto__` to traverse up the chain.

Answer (score 2):

*2 things happen here :*

1. How Object.create works
2. How prototype chain works.

It's *important* to understand what Object.create actually do.

`Object.create` does this (sort of) :

- Declare a local function `f`
- Set the  *`someobject`* to its prototype value ( `f.prototype = someobject`)
- return `new f`

`inherited_object` does **not** have foo ,bar .That's why you don't see them

But when you try to search them  , it  can't find it in  `inherited_object` so it goes through the prototype chain. And it finds it there.

Answer (score 1):

Because Object.create(...) uses some_object as a prototype of the "inherited_object". That means if you examine **inherited_object's** structure, it's **__proto__** member points to **some_object**.

In javascript if member is not directly found in the object, its prototype is being search for the same member. Hence you perceive them as "hidden"